# TypeError: showAddressDialog is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I am usually able to see the problem with these errors but I just can't see what the problem is this time.

This is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function showAddressDialog(aid,cno) {
            jQuery('#dialog-form').load('Includes/AddressDialog.aspx', {"AddressID":aid, "Cont_no":cno}, function() {});
            jQuery( '#dialog-form' ).dialog({
                modal: true,
                width: 750,
                height: 550,
                title: 'Addresses',
                buttons: {
                    'Close': function() {
                        jQuery( this ).dialog( 'close' );
                    }
                }
            });
        };
</script>
```

This is the html button that calls the function:

```
<input name="showAddressDialog" id="showAddressDialog" type="button" value="Show Addresses" onclick="showAddressDialog('1299','0')" />
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This error means the interpreter does not see the definition of the function. You need to make the function definition available before calling it by either moving that script block to the end of the `body` tag or wrap your entire function in an "Immediately Invoked Function" and add a click event handler on the element like this

```
(function() {
    jQuery("#showAddressDialog").click(function() {
        showAddressDialog('1299', '0');
    });

    function showAddressDialog(aid,cno) {
        jQuery('#dialog-form').load('Includes/AddressDialog.aspx', {"AddressID":aid, "Cont_no":cno}, function() {});
        jQuery( '#dialog-form' ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 750,
            height: 550,
            title: 'Addresses',
            buttons: {
                'Close': function() {
                    jQuery( this ).dialog( 'close' );
                }
            }
        });
    };
})();
```

The reason you need to wrap it in another function like this

```
jQuery("#showAddressDialog").click(function() {
        showAddressDialog('1299', '0');
});
```

is because so that you can pass parameters to that even handler. If your event handler did not need any extra parameters, you could just add that event handler to your `input` element like this

```
jQuery("#showAddressDialog").click(showAddressDialog);
```

Comment: Putting it in an IIFE will move it out of global scope, and the OP would not be able to reference it in HTML...